# Проект Qt завершается с кодом -1073741515

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, qtcreator

Создаю простенькую программку с OpenCV и QtCreator.
В pro файл добавляю это

```
INCLUDEPATH+=C:\\OpenCV2.2\\pro\\include
INCLUDEPATH+=C:\\OpenCV2.2\\pro\\include\\opencv
LIBS+=C:\\OpenCV2.2\\pro\\lib\\libopencv_core220d.dll.a
LIBS+=C:\\OpenCV2.2\\pro\\lib\\libopencv_contrib220d.dll.a
LIBS+=C:\\OpenCV2.2\\pro\\lib\\libopencv_features2d220d.dll.a
LIBS+=C:\\OpenCV2.2\\pro\\lib\\libopencv_flann220d.dll.a
LIBS+=C:\\OpenCV2.2\\pro\\lib\\libopencv_highgui220d.dll.a
LIBS+=C:\\OpenCV2.2\\pro\\lib\\libopencv_objdetect220d.dll.a
LIBS+=C:\\OpenCV2.2\\pro\\lib\\libopencv_video220d.dll.a
LIBS+=C:\\OpenCV2.2\\pro\\lib\\libopencv_legacy220d.dll.a
LIBS+=C:\\OpenCV2.2\\pro\\lib\\libopencv_calib3d220d.dll.a
LIBS+=C:\\OpenCV2.2\\pro\\lib\\libopencv_ffmpeg220d.dll.a
LIBS+=C:\\OpenCV2.2\\pro\\lib\\libopencv_imgproc220d.dll.a
LIBS+=C:\\OpenCV2.2\\pro\\lib\\libopencv_ml220d.dll.a`
```

Непосредственно код программы:

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    IplImage *img = cvLoadImage("D:\\pn.png");
    cvNamedWindow("Hello, QT! From OpenCV!");
    cvShowImage("Hello, QT! From OpenCV!", img);
    cvWaitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

Пример взят из интернета. При запуске завершается с кодом -1073741515 или 255. С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: ошибка с кодом -1073741515 значит, что какие то dll не были найдены в процессе запуска.

Comment: Не подскажете, что с этим делать?

Comment: нагуглить dependency walker и посмотреть, какие библиотеки не нашло. Потом подложить их к exe или прописать в путях поиска.

Comment: Спасибо за совет) Что значит прописать в путях поиска?

Comment: Скорее всего ты не добавил путь к каталогу %OPENCV_DIR%\bin в пути.
http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-last-rst/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html#windowssetpathandenviromentvariable

Comment: Всем спасибо! Помогло добавление dll в папку с exe.